# UIButton addTarget doesn't get called

Tags: swift, uibutton, uialertcontroller, addtarget

I'm trying to create a `UIAlertController` that has a `UITextField` inside.

The text field should have a button in its right side (using the `rightView` attribute). The button should view an image instead of a regular text button.

When I'm clicking the button of the text field, the function `btnClicked` should be called, but it never actually gets called.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Testing", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
alert.addTextField { (field) in
    let chk = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    chk.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 18, height: 18)
    chk.tag = i
    chk.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    chk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    // I also tried the following:
    // chk.addTarget(chk, action: #selector(self.btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

                    
    chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .normal)
    chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .selected)
    chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .highlighted)
    chk.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    chk.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
                    
    field.rightView = chk
    field.rightViewMode = .always
}
            
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the `btnClicked` function:

```
@objc func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("test")
}
```

For now, I'm just trying to print `test`, just to see if it works, but nothing is getting printed to the console.

Am I doing something wrong? So far I couldn't manage to call the `btnClicked` function after clicking on the `chk` button.

Comment: does the button get highlighted when you press it? I think the alert controller won't even pass it the touch  events.

Comment: The button does not get highlighted when I press it. Do you know how can I make the alert controller to pass the touch events?

Comment: I have run your code, there is some compiler error, I have fixed them. It works perfectly. It prints "test" every time in the console whenever I tapped on the button.

Comment: How did you fix the error? What did you change in the code?

Comment: The compile error is related to Swift version. Default code also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have run your code, there is some compiler error, I have fixed them. It works perfectly. It prints "test" every time in the console whenever I tapped on the button.*

```
 func showAlert(){
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Testing", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (field) in
        let chk = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        chk.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 18, height: 18)
        chk.tag = 1
        chk.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        chk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        // I also tried the following:
        // chk.addTarget(chk, action: #selector(self.btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .normal)
        chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .selected)
        chk.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle"), for: .highlighted)
        chk.imageView!.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        chk.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true

        field.rightView = chk
        field.rightViewMode = .always
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("test")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change target `chk` to `self` (or where your `btnClicked` function is in)

```
chk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: I tried it and works. (the button is invisible, clicked to right of the textfield)

Comment: I have just tried running it, but it doesn't work for me. By the way, the button is not invisible

Comment: btw, if you set `chk.addTarget(chk,..` it should crash. Are you sure you can press the button?

Comment: I press it, but nothing happens. It just stays as is. I guess that the touch event just not happens

Comment: where does `btnClicked` located and where do you present your alert?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218361/discussion-between-omerfarukozturk-and-ido-naveh).